# Can't download files. Garbage code displays

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, http-headers, download

I have  Drupal website and my users can no longer download files. (docx, xlsx, etc). In firefox ***only***, when the user clicks a link to download a file the page displays garbage code.

I read elsewhere the solution is to add the following, but it didn't work. Instead, the user is prompted with a dummy download for the application type each time the page reloads.

drupal_set_header('Content-type: application/octet-stream; charset=utf-8');

I have a simple module which has a page that spits out the links to the files. In this module I added the above to the hook_init() function.

[image: Screenshot of the garbage code]

I've never encountered this problem before, and I'm not sure why it started. Any help would of course be greatly appreciated. If I find a solution before someone replies with the answer I'll post it here for future reference.

Comment: Also, this only occurs in firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because MIME types are not set correctly. 
You can either force Drupal to set the `content-type header` to appropriate MIME type, or set it at the server side.

I'd recommend you to do it in the .htaccess file in your files folder (sites/default/files by default)

Just put the below code in the .htaccess file (or you can create a new .htaccess file if it's not there).

```
AddType  application/octet-stream  .doc .xls .pdf
```

Note that hook_init() gets fired at every normal page request. **Never** do this in this hook or you will end up facing many problems.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a roll for your MIME:

```
drupal_set_header('Content-type: application/force-download');
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work either. Perhaps I'm implementing it wrong? I tried placing it within the hook_init and the page_callback itself. Neither cases worked. I was prompted to download a dummy file by the same name "application/force-download" with each page refresh. I must continue with my search. Perhaps a JS solution... hmm...

Comment: Whoa, sorry I just saw this popup. Have you figured out the issue yet? I don't think anything JS-based would help -- seems to be a MIME/browser issue. If all else fails, you could zip up the file with a few lines and have them download that?

Comment: In the end, nothing really worked as I hoped. Because this issue was only present for FireFox users, I decided to use a work around so I can move onto other issues. Thanks!